# Reputation graph - what do green/red numbers mean?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I assume green is the increase in rep, but what's the red? I see 0s or negatives. No idea what they mean. Can a link be added to explain?

Comment: Isn't this pretty obvious?

Comment: @Rich B: It's a rush to ask the most obvious questions before they're all duplicates.

Comment: @Rich B: I call dibs on asking what language Stack Overflow's content is.

Comment: @Welbog: Has anyone asked about problems with certain characters in links yet?

Comment: If green is 'go', red would be... uh... I better look this up.

Comment: I'm going to ask how to click links on Stack Overflow since I have seen no documentation regarding its best practices.

Comment: Better be careful Welbog, your question on best link clicking practices may be very subjective.

Comment: Let's just do a catch-all question: **Can you explain everything the Stack Overflow team has done to make SO usable so that things don't need to be explained?** You see, I'm having trouble with these idiot-proof features. They're giving me a hard time.

Comment: "If I use StackOverflow, will my power requirements for my PC change?"

Comment: My Favorite from Yesterday: **"How Do I ask Questions on StackOverflow?**

Comment: I feel like mule-kicking a four year old.

Comment: "​**How do you post a comment on a question with an obvious answer?**​"

Comment: What if he was color blind?

Comment: He wouldn't have noticed a difference between the colours, then.

Comment: Man, I wish I could be as smart a$$ you welbog. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Red represents a loss of repuation from anything, not just downvotes, this includes:

- Bounties placed on questions
- 100 rep loss from offensive votes
- Downvotes

Answer (score 5):

Red is for down-votes. You will see -2 for every down-vote someone gives you, and -1 for every down-vote you give. -100 for for questions/answers flagged offensive. It will also include any bounties you have set.

I don't think this has been discussed, so I'm not sure I can find a link to add.